# Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

When running `rake db:migrate`, I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

---

I've looked at other people's questions on here and none of their solutions have helped me, for example:

**Solution One**

```
mysql.server start
```

returns:

```
Starting MySQL
```

. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/something.pid).

**Solution Two**

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

returns:

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'

Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

---

**Further notes:**
I tried reinstalling mysql using homebrew, which was successful, and I'm still receiving the same errors:

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Check if mysql is running and the socket file. If MySQL is running but the socket file is not there then check my.cnf if mysql is configured to listen on that socket. Chances are there that it is listening on port 3306 which is default for MySQL.

Comment: When I try to check that it's running, I get this error: `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!`

Comment: Try `ps aux|grep mysql`

Comment: You can also try `top` and type `-o` then `vsize` which will sort by memory consumption and MySQL if running will be near top as it consumes quite a bit of memory compared to other system processes.

Comment: Mysql isn't there, so it mustn't be running. How can I get it to start?

Comment: I do not know how to start MySQL on homebrew on Mac. I know only on Linux. Please search or wait for someone to answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**I solved it!**

First, go to `database.yml`

Change `host: localhost` to `host: 127.0.0.1`

That's it!

**Edit:** This works temporarily, but when I restarted my computer today it began throwing up the same errors. The fix was to just install mysql from the website, then my application could successfully connect to mysql again.

Answer (score 8):

env：rails5 mysql5.7.32

As a supplement, I also encountered the problem `'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'`, but the reason for the error was caused by the socket files

database.yml

```
default: &default
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

login mysql `mysql -uroot -p` then `show variables like 'socket';`

```
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                       |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| socket        | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

so change database.yml

```
default: &default
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock # The line can also be deleted
```

Comment: what if there is no mysqld.sock file?

Comment: @tagaism I think this may be another problem:'mysqld.sock does not exist?', the solution I found is actually to restart the mysql service to re-establish the socket. https://serverfault.com/a/305056/420636

Comment: Cannot login. 
Says: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in an Ubuntu server (with ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.3) and fixed it by simply removing the line:

```
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

from `config/database.yml`, which must have allowed the connection to be established according to defaults.

Answer (score -4):

Another answer, type in terminal(zsh):

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

and then

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

should be ok.

Comment: there's not much to learn in your solution since you didn't explain much about it :(